# How to calculate ranking based on two different attributes from two tables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have two tables `tbl_Generate` and `tbl_Status`. `tbl_Generate` has two columns one is `TGenerate`(having only boolean value 1 or 0) and and `Emp_Id` Table is something like this:-

```
 T_ID |Tgenerate |Emp_ID
 -----|----------|-------
   1  | 0        |101
   2  | 1        |101
   3  | 1        |101
   4  | 0        |102
   5  | 1        |102
   6  | 1        |102
   7  | 1        |102
   8  | 0        |102
```

I have another table `tbl_Status` It has also having two imp columns Status (Status has four fixed value `'Delivered','Pending','Didn't Call','Refused'`) and `Emp_Id`.

```
 status_Id | Status      |Emp_ID
 ----------|-------------|------
    1      | Delivered   |  101
    2      | Didn't Call |  102
    3      | Pending     |  101
    4      | Refused     |  101
    5      | Delivered   |  101
    6      | Refused     |  102
    7      | Delivered   |  102
    8      | Pending     |  102
    9      | Didn't Call |  101
    10     | Pending     |  102
```

I want to calculate ranking for every `Emp_Id` based on who have generated more no of `TGenerate`(For ex in `tbl_Generate` 101 has generated total 2 and 102 generated total 3 `Tgenerate`) and `Emp_Id` who have highest count of status as delieverd(For ex 101 has total 2 delivered count).

So how do I write sql query to get rank on the basis of those two attributes(`TGenerate` and `Status`). And How do I get total count whose status is not Delivered. P.S.:- I am using SQL Server 2012.

Comment: Which attribute should be the first to be sorted? count of delivered `Status` or `Tgenerate` = 1? I mean what if two `Emp_ID` are such that one has more delivered and other has more Tgenerate = 1 entries?

Comment: What should happen where there is a employee present in generate table and not in status table and vice versa?

Comment: @Vashi Count of delivered 'Status' should be sorted first. Means If two Emp_id are there one having highest Tgenerate and other one having highest Delivered count. First rank would goes to the second one having highest delivered count

Comment: @Pரதீப் In your mentioned case, ranking will be generated based on Tgenerate count and we will take Count of Delivery as 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you need something like this

```
SELECT T.Emp_Id,
       [Rank] = Dense_rank() OVER (ORDER BY Tgenerate_Cnt DESC, Delivered_Cnt DESC)
FROM   (SELECT Emp_ID,
               Tgenerate_Cnt = Count(*)
        FROM   tbl_Generate
        WHERE  Tgenerate = 1
        GROUP  BY Emp_ID) T
       LEFT JOIN (SELECT Emp_ID,
                         Delivered_Cnt = Count(*)
                  FROM   tbl_Status
                  WHERE  Status = 'Delivered'
                  GROUP  BY Emp_ID) S
              ON T.Emp_ID = S.Emp_ID
```

Comment: Worked!! Thank You very much.

Answer (score 1):

Try the below query.

Note - It will take only those `Emp_ID` that are present in both the tables since an INNER JOIN is being used.

```
SELECT TG.EMP_ID, 
DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY TS.COUNT_DEL, TG.COUNT_TG) AS YOUR_RANK
FROM
(SELECT EMP_ID, SUM(CASE WHEN TGENERATE = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT_TG FROM TBL_GENERATE GROUP BY EMP_ID) TG
INNER JOIN
(SELECT EMP_ID, SUM(CASE WHEN STATUS = 'DELIVERED' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS COUNT_DEL FROM TBL_STATUS GROUP BY EMP_ID) TS
ON TG.EMP_ID = TS.EMP_ID;
```

Comment: You are great. Thank you very much for your help.